# Nested Menu support in Apache ISIS

Tags: isis

I have a large set of entities . but i am facing problem to manage action menus. what i want is something like :

basemenu1

```
 |
 __ submenu1
       |
        __subsubmenu1
               |
                _ subsubsubmenu1
```

Otherwise there are lot of menu on screen and it does not look good.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported in Isis, yet, I'm afraid.

I would just remark that having lots of cascading submenus is a "code smell" (and wouldn't make for a pleasant user experience, to boot).

If you have lots of domain service actions, you might want to move some of them onto objects, to make those objects behaviourally complete (rather than anaemic data containers).

Or, if you would prefer to keep the behaviour implemented in domain services, you can still make those actions *appear* as if they are implemented on objects by using contributed actions, as per [1][2]

EDIT: you could also try associating actions with properties/collections, so that they are rendered close to the member(s) that they act upon.  [3]

HTH
Dan

[1] http://isis.apache.org/applib-guide/how-tos/how-to-01-062-How-to-decouple-dependencies-using-contributions.html

[2] https://isis.apache.org/applib-guide/domain-services/how-to-09-020-How-to-write-a-typical-domain-service.html

[3] http://isis.apache.org/core/dynamic-layouts.html

Comment: Hi Dan,thanks for quick reply . Actually our problem is , we have more then 60 domain objects and each have corresponding domain service containing 3 or more actions. So i am having difficulty grouping these menus . It will be helpful if i can have nested menus like on datanucleus website :http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/many_to_many.html#set

Comment: Raise a ticket if you want.  But I've also edited my answer to suggest another option, so check that out as well.

Comment: The new option you provided is good if we have more actions in one domain object . So instead of service menu we can use dynamic layout to accommodate more actions. But in my case i have more then 60 entities and i want to group them in menus . I am raising a ticket. kindly let me know how can i use nested menus.

Comment: I don't quite follow - in Isis, entities aren't shown in the domain service menus.  What I think you mean is that you have one domain service (a repository/factory) per entity (perhaps 'find' and 'create') and you want to organize these better?

Comment: you are correct Dan. i mentioned it wrongly. but i think you got my problem.